# Button in custom UITableView header doesn't respond until scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, ios7

I've got an ungrouped UITableView with a custom header view, returned in `viewForHeaderInSection` (there's only one section). At the bottom of this custom header view there is a clickable custom UIButton. At the moment I'm having an issue that this button doesn't respond to taps until the table has been scrolled (any tiny scroll will make it active). Oddly enough, when I change the style of the table view to a grouped UITableView, this issue doesn't happen but I get a grey margin between my header view and the rest of the cells (I've tried working around this but it always results in the UIButton being completely obscured).

Does anyone know where this problem might come from? What kind of functions get called on scroll that might affect the responsiveness of a subview in my header view?

EDIT: Here's a (heavily redacted) screenshot of the view I'm talking about. Everything above the cells (including the UIButton) is part of the header returned by `viewForHeaderInSection`.

[image: The table view]

ANOTHER EDIT: I ticked 'clip subviews' in my header view in Interface Builder, and found that part of the header, from halfway down the video view downwards (including the button) was clipped away until I first scrolled the view. This must indicate part of the problem. Any idea what might be happening here? I've tried logging every function call in the table view controller and haven't found anything happening when I make that first scroll.

Comment: can you shared screen shot of table view?

Comment: Sure - I'll need to blur some stuff out to keep it anonymous but I could share it. Would it be best to have a shot of the Nib or the app running in the simulator?

Comment: app running in simulator.

Comment: @benwad Did you find a solution to this odd behaviour? I am seeing the same in a tableview header I have.